# How to multiply LONG and FLOAT in Java

Tags: java

I need to multiply two numbers (for example, **A** and **B**) and return the result (**A*B**).

**Condition:**

**number A**: Any number between **0** to **Long.MAX_VALUE** ( i.e., 0 <= A <= 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

**number B**: Any number between **0** to **10000.0000000000**) // Remember 'B' will be a decimal number with upto 10 decimal places

If the result of (**A * B**) contains decimal, then, round up to the next higher integer.
for example,

1. if the result of A x B = 10.1 => 11
2. if the result of A x B = 10.5 => 11
3. if the result of A x B = 10.9 => 11
4. if the result of A x B >= LONG_MAX, then return LONG_MAX (i.e. 9223372036854775807)

I wrote a simple function as mentioned but it is giving me strange result!! Can you please correct me why the function is failing?

```
static long multiply(long A, float B)
{
    long result = (long) Math.ceil(A * B);
    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(multiply(10L, 1.11F)); // 10 x 1.11 => 11.1 => 12 [PASS]
    
    System.out.println(multiply(10L, 1.17F)); //10 x 1.17 => 11.7 => 12 [PASS]
    
    System.out.println(multiply(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1.11F)); // 9223372036854775807 x 1.11 => 9223372036854775807 [PASS]
    
    System.out.println(multiply(9999999L, 9.9999F)); // 9999999 x 9.9999 => 99,998,990.0001 => 99,998,991 [FAIL]
                                                     // I am getting 99998992, instead of 99998991 !!
    
    System.out.println(multiply(4611686018427387908L, 1.0F)); // 4611686018427387908L x 1 => 4611686018427387908 [FAIL]
                                                              // I am getting 4611686018427387904 instead of 4611686018427387908
    
    System.out.println(multiply(96113850L, 1.0F)); // 96113850 x 1 => 96113850 [FAIL]
                                                   // I am getting 96113848 instead of 96113850
}
```

Last 3 test cases are failing. Please let me know how to correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: Float is almost never the answer. Double is more precise. You might have to use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if "'B' will be a decimal number with upto 10 decimal places", then it needs to be a `double`, not a `float`.

To prevent loss of precision during the calculation, it needs to be done using `BigDecimal`.

```java
static long multiply(long a, double b) {
    if (a < 0 || b < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative value not allowed");
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.valueOf(a)
            .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(b))
            .setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
    return (result.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)) < 0
            ? result.longValue() : Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(multiply(10L, 1.11)); // 12
System.out.println(multiply(10L, 1.17)); // 12
System.out.println(multiply(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1.11)); // 9223372036854775807
System.out.println(multiply(9999999L, 9.9999)); // 99998991
System.out.println(multiply(4611686018427387908L, 1.0)); // 4611686018427387908
System.out.println(multiply(96113850L, 1.0)); // 96113850
```

Answer (score 3):

Use BigDecimal to calculate and round in the Decimal number system with almost infinite range:

```
static long multiply(long A, float B)
{
    return new BigDecimal(A)
           .multiply(new BigDecimal(B))
           .max(new BigDecimal(Long.MAX_VALUE)
           .setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP)
           .longValue();
}
```